# Is my mono installation broken?

Tags: mono, automapper

I'm running mono 2.10.6 on openSUSE 12.1. Shouldn't there be a System.Data.dll in either /usr/lib/mono/4.0 or /usr/lib/mono/2.0 ?

I'm testing a .NET application compiled on windows. The application has a reference to automapper and I get the following error when I try to run the application:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception  
was thrown by the type initializer for AutoMapper.Mappers.DataReaderMapper --->
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data,
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
dependencies.

File name: 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Here is the output of mono --version:

```
linux-19xt:~ # mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.6 (tarball Sat Oct 29 18:16:09 UTC 2011)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          debugger softdebug
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Comment: The problem is `compiled on Windows`. The structure of executable is different on different platforms. It needs to be compiled on openSUSE.

Comment: @cole-johnson Thanks, but not fully true. .NET assemblies are _interpreted_ by the CLR on windows and by mono, an open source .net framework implementation.

Comment: They contain the same MSIL, yes. But the structure of Windows PE executables and ELF Linux executables are different. Also, as `Lex Li` pointed out, the signing algorithm is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install "mono-complete" or "monodevelop" and you should no longer see this issue. On unbuntu the command is...

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

or for the monodevelop ide (which also installs mono-complete)

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

I had 3 vms (1 with just the mono runtime installed, 1 with the monodevelop ide installed, and 1 with mono-complete installed) all running the exact same executable but only one that saw the issue you described was the one with only the mono runtime installed. Running the "mono-complete" command above fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Mono's assemblies do not have the same PublicKeyToken like Microsoft's, as Microsoft won't share the keys with Mono team, so you need to configure AutoMapper to ignore PublicKeyToken.

However, I am not sure if AutoMapper can be configured to work with Mono, as there is no official announcement anywhere, and there is an issue open on GitHub,

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/217

And there is a mail thread about that, too,

http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/773193330f7d12ef?pli=1